# how to use output of one command as another command in linux

Tags: linux, unix

what I am looking for is, use the output of one command as " EXACTLY THE OTHER COMMAND" in Linux ?

for ex:

```
[root@ip-10-0-0-136 ~]# echo hi
hi
[root@ip-10-0-0-136 ~]
```

now this "hi" I want to use as immediate command and execute. 
how can I do that ?

so, should be like :

```
[root@ip-10-0-0-136 ~]# echo hi
hi
[root@ip-10-0-0-136 ~]# hi
```

can it be possible ?

Please suggest

edit 1 :

please refer the specific example :

```
[root@ip-10-0-0-136 ~]# aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region eu-central-1
docker login -u AWS -p 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 https://890543041640.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com
[root@ip-10-0-0-136 ~]# !$
eu-central-1
bash: eu-central-1: command not found
[root@ip-10-0-0-136 ~]# $
bash: $: command not found
[root@ip-10-0-0-136 ~]#
```

Comment: what about `$(echo hi)`?

Comment: try `$(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region eu-central-1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `$(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region eu-central-1)`
This will execute the output of the command in the parenthesis. In your case the command `docker login -u AWS -p eyJwYX..` will get executed

Refer: https://superuser.com/questions/935374/difference-between-and-in-shell-script

Answer (score 2):

You can use command substitution:

```
[root@ip-10-0-0-136 ~]# $(echo hi)
```

Which is identical to

```
[root@ip-10-0-0-136 ~]# `echo hi`
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is possible using `!$`. If I use 
`[root@ip~ppp]$ echo cd
cd
[root@ip~ppp]$ !$
cd
[root@ip~]$`

Here `cd` command is executed

Comment: Thanks. I have modified my question with specific example . can you please check...

Answer (score 0):

I think simply you can pipe some output and feed it to bash command.

```
echo 'ls' | bash
```